# ExecuteDataSet timeout occurs on very quick stored procedure

Tags: c#, ado.net, dataset

I'm try to debug an issue that's cropped up in one of our legacy systems.

This is the code in question

```
DataSet content = new DataSet();

Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();
DbCommand cmdSearchQuestionLibrary = db.GetStoredProcCommand("CUP_Reports_GetTrainerPerformanceReport");
db.AddInParameter(cmdSearchQuestionLibrary, "@PartnerID", DbType.Int64, partnerId);
db.AddInParameter(cmdSearchQuestionLibrary, "@StartDate", DbType.DateTime, dtStartDate);
db.AddInParameter(cmdSearchQuestionLibrary, "@EndDate", DbType.DateTime, dtEndDate);
db.AddInParameter(cmdSearchQuestionLibrary, "@TrainerId", DbType.Int32, trainerId);
db.AddInParameter(cmdSearchQuestionLibrary, "@AssessmentType", DbType.Int32, assessmentType);

content = db.ExecuteDataSet(cmdSearchQuestionLibrary);
```

The timeout occurs on the `db.ExecuteDataSet`. I traced this in SQL Server Profiler and run the same query against the same database and it's taking less than a second to return the data.

If I extend the timeout I can see that it's taking over a minute to return the same data which isn't acceptable.

Is there something going on here that I'm missing? I wondered if `db.GetStoredProcCommand` is opening a connection that needs to be closed and it's just waiting for that connection to close.

Comment: Database factory is part of the namespace Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data it is a "Method for invoking a default Database object. Reads default settings from
  //     the ConnectionSettings.config file." which is <add name="ScreenTest" connectionString="Data Source=svr-staging;Initial Catalog=ScreenTest_BUPLAS;Integrated Security=true;"
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>

Comment: I would be tempted to run a Visual Studio profiler and see where exactly in code the hold up is and track down the issue that way. However how big is the dataset that you are creating and using up memory with?

Comment: It only returns 1 row of data with 4 columns all very small bits of data. i.e. 67.5,Connect,2,Cambridge Admin

Comment: Hmm... there are some known issues with regards to Enterprise Library Data Access Application Block that adding parameters can be like 100 times slower that directly using ADO.NET? I'd be tempted to give the direct ADO method a test and see how that turns out, see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310070 for easy reference example.

Comment: Have a quick read of http://entlib.codeplex.com/workitem/32858

Answer (score 1):

After trying several things it turns out that the solution was to add `WITH Recompile` onto the Stored Procedure. Seems that the DB was holding onto a bad execution plan.